# How to make this javascript code better? works for A-B-C destinations, but is not dynamic, there's a bag when I want to go to destination "D"

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Could be an algorithm issue.

used

```
var markers = new Map(); (for markers)
var routes = new Array(); (for lines from pt a to b and etc)
```

---

```
const step = (pointsObj) => {
    if (pointsObj.i < routes.length) {

        if (routes.length > 1)

        // move the user along the line by 1 step ()
        var pointA = routes[pointsObj.i];
        var pointB = routes[pointsObj.i + 1];

        // user moving gradually to the next point
        userMarker.setLatLng(
            new L.LatLng(
                userMarker.getLatLng().lat + (pointB.lat - pointA.lat) / maxNumSteps,
                userMarker.getLatLng().lng + (pointB.lng - pointA.lng) / maxNumSteps
            )
        );

        // number of steps user taking to move forward

        currentNumSteps++;
        // once the user reaches point B, set pointA = pointB and pointB = point C
        if (currentNumSteps == maxNumSteps) pointsObj.i++;
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you further elaborate the question?

Comment: can see A and B, but no C except in a comment ... guess B will be `pointA` and C will be `pointB` ... if you `pointsObj.i++;` again, then `C` will be `pointA` and D will be `pointB`?

Comment: @Bravo

yes, it should be like
PointA (A) to PointB (B);
PointA (C) to PointB (D);
PointA (D) to PointB (E) ;

Something like this

Comment: but I'm having trouble and is getting me wrong output/bag when my object goes to C to D it's not doing what I want

Comment: what's it doing instead? error in the console when `pointsObj.i + 1` === `routes.length` perhaps?  you probably want `if (pointsObj.i < routes.length - 1` because you always look at `i` and `i + 1` ... so, when `.i === routes.lenght - 1` there is no `routes[.i + 1]`

Comment: @Bravo
oh I see my error...:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')

Comment: @Bravo

my object is not moving to direction D , E, and etc, but going on the wrong direction

Comment: oh no, I can't see your data to tell you what you're doing wrong

Comment: any ideas how to make this dynamic

Comment: @Khalil any thoughts?